# Using pivot_longer on list columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to stack several list columns on top of each other using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package, but I keep getting an error.  Here is a simple example...

```r
tibble(
  date = c(rep(1,500), rep(2,500)),
  size = runif(1000,10,10000),
  var1 = rnorm(1000),
  var2 = rnorm(1000)
) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  nest() %>%
  rename(all = data) %>%
  mutate(
    not_tiny = map(all, filter, size >= 1000),
    large = map(all, filter, size >= 5000)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(all, not_tiny, large), names_to = "subset", values_to = "data")
```

If I try to run this, the error says

```
Error: No common type for `all` <list_of<
  tbl_df<
    size: double
    var1: double
    var2: double
  >
>> and `not_tiny` <list>.
```

The desired output is

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   date [2]
   date subset   data              
  <dbl> <chr>    <list>            
1     1 all      <tibble [500 × 3]>
2     2 all      <tibble [500 × 3]>
3     1 not_tiny <tibble [448 × 3]>
4     2 not_tiny <tibble [451 × 3]>
5     1 large    <tibble [239 × 3]>
6     2 large    <tibble [264 × 3]>
```

This is the output from the no longer supported `gather` function that `pivot_longer` replaced.  Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Not getting any error for me `packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Comment: Interesting.  That is the version of `tidyr` that I have.  I just started a fresh R session, and tried again, and I am still getting the same error.  Can anyone else confirm if they are seeing the error, or is this something unique to my system?

Comment: I used `R 3.6.2` with the devel version of `dplyr` and `packageVersion('purrr')#
[1] ‘0.3.3’`

Comment: Upgrading to the development version of `dplyr` fixed it.  Thanks for the help!